# How can I send emails to multiple recipients with Ruby Mail.rb

Tags: ruby, email

I've written a small script to send out emails with attachments in Ruby. It works like a charm as long as there is a single recipient, however I need to send out mails to a list of recipients. The recipients are stored in a yaml file, which is being read by the script and then emails are sent to each recipient with the help of a loop:

```
Mail.defaults do
delivery_method :smtp, options
end

mail['mail_to'].each do |i|
    mail = Mail.new do 
        to i
        from mail['mail_from']
        subject mail_subject
        body mail_body
        add_file    :filename => 'Report.pdf', :content => File.read(global['filename_pdf'])
end
    mail.deliver!
end
```

However this only works for the first recipient, afterwards ruby throws this:

```
/home/juwi/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:5:in `check_delivery_params': An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address. (ArgumentError)
from /home/juwi/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:98:in `deliver!'
from /home/juwi/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:248:in `deliver!'
from main.rb:47:in `block in <main>'
from main.rb:33:in `each'
from main.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

I don't really understand why that happens. So I'd love to be enlightened, here!

Comment: Try `pp mail['mail_to']` and see if there are any invalid (blank?) entries.

Comment: mail['mail_to'] is not the problem. mail['mail_from'] gets nil on the second run of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer after realizing that I get nil from the second run of the loop onwards. It seems, that Ruby tries to iterate over the "from" field as if it were an array. So I explicitly added a variable for it, and that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that might work in many contexts is to use a comma separated list in the `to` field - eg.

```
  mail = Mail.new do
    from    'me@my_domain.com'
    to      'me@my_domain.com, him@elsewhere.com'
    subject 'test'
    body    'message'
  end
```

From: https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/elements/address_list.rb

> Mail::AddressList requires a correctly formatted group or mailbox list
>   per RFC2822 or RFC822.  It also handles all obsolete versions in those
>   RFCs.